# Specify joint conditional and excluding columns with WHERE multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Well, I'm using MYSQL and I cannot specify specific columns multiple times. I know that the following code is wrong but it is to better understand what I am trying to do.

Note: id_follow_book = id book

I need to specify in the same query, from `id_follow_book`  select some id in specific and with some specific chapters. With IN it does not help me, because I would select the id to follow the books well, but then I would not pick the correct chapters for each follow-up. Exist the possibility that the user is not following a book or id_follow_book, maybe even none. What I'm trying to return those that are followed by the user.

```
SELECT id_follow_book, num_chapt
FROM Follow, Chapters
WHERE id_user = 1 AND
id_follow_book = id_chapter_book AND
(id_follow_book = 15 AND num_chapt = (10+1)) AND/OR
(id_follow_book = 25 AND num_chapt = (5+1)) AND/OR
(id_follow_book = 30 AND num_chapt = (23+1))
```

The sum numbers are variables. 
I tried too with CASE WHEN, but I didn't achieve it. Thanks and sorry for my english.

```
Follow                                      Chapters

id_follow_book   id_user                 id_chapter_book   num_chapt
    30                1                       30              6
    25                1                       30              5
    13                1                       30              4
    21                1                       25             24
                                              25             23
```

Expected result:

```
id_follow_book    num_chapt  (this is last viewed chapt of user, this solutioned) 
    30                  6
    25                 24
```

Comment: `Follow` and `Chapters` are your tables (two different tables)?

Comment: yeah they it different tables

Comment: Normally, it would be easier to answer questions like yours if the structure of the tables (at least schematically) is presented along with some sample data and desired result. Right now I'm not sure I understand what you wish to achieve.

Comment: I edited now, It's done

Answer (score 1):

Try using IN operator:

```
SELECT id_follow_book, num_chapt
FROM Follow inner join Chapters on 
id_follow_book = id_chapter_book 
WHERE id_user = 1 AND 
id_follow_book in( 15,25,30) AND num_chapt in(11,6,24)
```

Comment: You are missing the `ON` after the `inner join`.

Comment: @fa06 this continue showing the same result. It allow that the IDs that aren't being followed, they're being included

Comment: can you please include sample data and your expected result with example

Comment: updated the answer ,but you forget to add chaptertable data

Comment: sorry I was wrong, like i said IN is not an option, because chapters are not being selected correctly

Comment: then what is logic of chapter selection? @santa_oscuro